# How to make a Python telegram bot wait for user input?

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Example: I send /weather to a bot and he asked me city. How to make him wait to reply?

Answer (score 1):

`ConversationHandler` can be used to achieve the purpose. Python-telegram-bot [conversationbot2.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py) example gives a good reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the InlineKeyboardButton for that. It pops up a button for the user to press on. You can 'wait' for the user to input the data that way